# Do I apply a sharp to all the same notes?

Tags: guitar, notation, sheet-music

I play guitar and for one of my songs, the sheet music shows sharps for only higher notes and not the lower notes. Do I apply the sharps to the lower notes? For example, G on string 1 is a sharp but it doesn't specify that G on string 6 is a sharp.[image]

Comment: In general it is worth using the Search function (top left hand side of screen) before posting a question to make sure you aren't just repeating a question that has already been asked.

Answer (score 5):

That's the **key signature**, which tells which *letter name* notes are sharpened. There's only need to put a sharp sign there on the F line, and musos will assume all F notes throughout the piece are sharpened, regardless of which octave they're in., unless cancelled by the natural sign (♮). The same goes for the other sharps, and all flats, in flat keys.

In fact, just playing the piece with *only* the top line F sharpened, and others played as naturals, would sound rather strange, wouldn't it?

However, if you find a stray sharp, flat or natural sign in front of a note somewhere else, that only lasts for the bar, and is known as an *accidental*. The ones you ask about aren't accidentals, they're put there *on purpose*!

Answer (score 1):

What you showed us is a key signature.  It sharpens all F, C, G and D notes in all octaves.

But there are also 'accidentals'.  They persist only until the next barline, and only at that exact pitch.

But, when that strict rule could cause confusion, a reminder 'cautionary accidental' is sensible.  Required, even.

[image]